# Access the compiled template in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I do elm.html() in the link function then I get the uncompiled template with `{{curly_brackets}}`. How do I get access to the compiled html where the `{{template_variables}}` have been replaced by the correct scope variables.

If this is not possible from the directive then what is a good alternative solution? Ultimately, the purpose of the directive is to get the height of the compiled element.

Here is a example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RfHx8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to let the Angular get finished before you check the height. To do this you can use setTimeout (or preferably the [$timeout service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)) with a zero delay:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
  $timeout(function(){
    var height = elm.height();
  },0,false);// No delay is necessary
 }
```

See the update for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RfHx8/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer that is how I was doing it. It feels a bit hacky though. I'm surprised that Angular doesn't have a more graceful way of doing this.